# How to make a custom activation function in keras with a learnable parameter?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, function

The answer to this question is generally to implement it as a new layer and do

```
layer = Dense(num_neurones)(previous_layer)
out = TheActivationFunction()(layer)
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050448/custom-activation-with-parameter).

However, I want to use it for an LSTM cell, like this

```
LSTM(units = num_units, activation = TheActivationFunction(), return_sequences = True)
```

Specifically, I would like to implement the function x -> tanh(beta * x) with *beta* a learnable parameter.